# Django is not able to run manage.py runserver how to solve?

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I'm trying to run manage.py server but it hit some error!
I've just trying to print hello in web but it insn't working

```
(venv) ubuntu@node:~/PycharmProjects/Oin$ python manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...

    Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x7fd985430158>
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/ubuntu/PycharmProjects/Oin/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 542, in url_patterns
        iter(patterns)
    TypeError: 'module' object is not iterable

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/ubuntu/PycharmProjects/Oin/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
        fn(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/ubuntu/PycharmProjects/Oin/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 120, in inner_run
        self.check(display_num_errors=True)
      File "/home/ubuntu/PycharmProjects/Oin/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in check
        include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
      File "/home/ubuntu/PycharmProjects/Oin/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 351, in _run_checks
        return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
      File "/home/ubuntu/PycharmProjects/Oin/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 73, in run_checks
        new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
      File "/home/ubuntu/PycharmProjects/Oin/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
        return check_resolver(resolver)
      File "/home/ubuntu/PycharmProjects/Oin/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
        return check_method()
      File "/home/ubuntu/PycharmProjects/Oin/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 400, in check
        warnings.extend(check_resolver(pattern))
      File "/home/ubuntu/PycharmProjects/Oin/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
        return check_method()
      File "/home/ubuntu/PycharmProjects/Oin/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 399, in check
        for pattern in self.url_patterns:
      File "/home/ubuntu/PycharmProjects/Oin/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 36, in __get__
        res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
      File "/home/ubuntu/PycharmProjects/Oin/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 549, in url_patterns
        raise ImproperlyConfigured(msg.format(name=self.urlconf_name))
    django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf '<module 'openin.urls' from '/home/ubuntu/PycharmProjects/Oin/openin/urls.py'>' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.
```

If you want any .py file feel free to ask
thank you! My project Dir : https://github.com/shreekantbatale2/Oinn

Comment: Looks like your `settings.py` file has some problems, or you have made circular imports. But without any details, it is hard to know what the exact problem is.

Comment: Hi @Shree - can we see your project's directory and file structure please.

Comment: HI @MichealJRoberts , Here it is my project Directory ->https://github.com/shreekantbatale2/Oinn

Comment: @Shree Please see my new answer and let me know if this helps...

Comment: @ShreeBatale Hi Shree, is there a reason why my correct answer has been removed and the question you said didn’t work is marked as the correct answer...

Comment: No i don't please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need either one of these two options in your `urls.py` file:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='home')
]
```

Or if you're using the `url` dispatcher, ***more likely* given what is in your `urls.py` file**:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', views.index, name='home')
]
```

Comment: hey thanks, it works fine. could you please tell me what is the difference between these two options 1)url(r'^', views.index, name='home') & 2path('', views.index, name='home') what is r in here?

Comment: @ShreeBatale Awesome - if you haven't already done so please give it an up vote as well :) I believe it is a change in Django 2.0 + where `path` (and `re-path`) are now the preferred options (using `re_path()` for matching regular expressions). Please see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/ for more information. `url()`still works in Django, it's more of a backwards compatibility option as there are so many tutorials where `url()` is used inside `urlpatterns = []`.

Comment: @ShreeBatale And could you accept the answer as well please :)

Comment: No worries :) Hope it makes sense - definitely always double down with the latest documentation when you want to get a sense of things. (Incidentally, I believe you had `urlPatterns` in your `urls.py` file when it should have been `urlpatterns`.

Answer (score 1):

In your repo 
Make following changes:
In openin/urls.py file: 
You have misspelled `urlpatterns` (You coded urlPatterns)
In file Oin/urls.py 
`path('^$', include('openin.urls')),` 
to 
`path('', include('openin.urls')),`

Comment: this is not working mate :/ Micheal gave an answer already and its worked fine for me , anyways thanks coder :)